# Blender keeps crashing/closing without log entry

Tags: modeling, windows

I have a problem with blender now and I don’t know why.
It keeps crashing constantly. I can work sometimes only 2 mins and sometimes upto 20. Then it closes without anything.
I reinstalled it with no success and even if I start it through the cmd in Windows with --debug-all nothing is shown other than the last command.
I installed Windows fresh and formated everything, but the problem still exists.

[image: Last Debug log]

My system:
Windows 10 Pro
AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
16 GB RAM
Geforce 1070 GTX
~100GB free space on SSD
Tried with Blender 2.8 and 2.9

I tried to find the crash log file but apparently the feature is disabled at the moment for windows.

If anyone can help, I would be glad!

Answer (score 1):

So if found out what the problem was:
My new G502 Logitech mouse.
I tried my old one and Blender never crashed again.

This post is closed.

Comment: Hello :). Glad you solved it. Please mark your question as accepted **✓**now :).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was from Security Center.

Google for `Windows Security Center`, and `apps permission`, some of Blender files are in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender`

My advice to you is to use portable version of Blender and copy anywhere but Windows Drive (C).

Comment: I will try! Thanks for the tip!